# Change src of html5 video tag depending on orientation of iPad

Tags: ipad, html, video, css, mobile-safari

Coding HTML5 page for use in iPad Mobile Safari that has  tag for embedding video file. Using CSS3 media queries to determine orientation of iPad, which works fine.

Now need to change the src of the video tag depending on orientation. In other words, there are two videos, one sized to work in landscape view and one to work in portrait view.

Any advice on how to approach this problem? I'm sure it's something pretty simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just insert the video tag using javascript, after it's looked at the document width and figured out the orientation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that, using this tutorial http://www.devinrolsen.com/javascript-mobile-orientation-detection/

However, when I rotate the iPad it does change the source of the video but doesn't 'reload' the page, hence you get a white background page with just the video on it.

Comment: Ah ok, you can use the - (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews function to trigger an action when the orientation changes, try putting a page reload within that.